# Type mismatch error in splitting a payload in mule3

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am creating variable which is an array in a transform (dw1). Then I am using for each to process each element of this array. Within for each another transform is being used which contains:

```
%var lineName = payload.split("-")[0]
```

But I am getting a type mismatch error for value selector. Please refer to image for error. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You want to use the splitBy function I believe

Comment: splitBy is not working.

Comment: Then you need to provide the customery input sample data and the expected output.

Comment: As George said you need to provide input and expected output data. And please do not use screenshots for textual data. The error is from a text log. It makes it more difficult to help. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrectly the operator. Note that DataWeave is not Java. DataWeave is a different language. You should not try to use Java methods nor syntax. Please read the documentation to learn more about DataWeave 1.0: https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/

The right way to write this would be:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload[0] splitBy "-"
```

I'm not sure if this will work as is because I don't have your input data nor expected output, but from a syntax perspective this is correct. You can use the same expression inside the variable definition.

Comment: Did the answer help?